# Loss of precision converting double to decimal in C#

Tags: c#, casting, precision

I'm trying to understand why I'm losing precision when I am calculating `4 * Math.Pow(256, 6)` and converting to decimal. This was the cause of an obscure bug, and while I've fixed it, I'm trying to understand what's going on.

My original code was:

```
    (decimal)(num * Math.Pow(256, exp))
```

This sometimes resulted in incorrect numbers (if `num>=4` and `exp>=6`), but was fixed by changing it to:

```
    num * (decimal)Math.Pow(256, exp)
```

Example:

```
    4 * Math.Pow(256, 6)             == 1125899906842624 (double)
    (decimal)(4 * Math.Pow(256, 6))  == 1125899906842620 (decimal)
    4 * (decimal)Math.Pow(256, 6)    == 1125899906842624 (decimal)
```

What confuses me more, is it doesn't do this if `num<=3`:

```
    1 * Math.Pow(256, 6)             == 281474976710656 (double)
    (decimal)(1 * Math.Pow(256, 6))  == 281474976710656 (decimal)
    1 * (decimal)Math.Pow(256, 6)    == 281474976710656 (decimal)
```

What's going on here?

---

Edit: I noticed a likely related problem, in that `Math.Exp(256,exp)` is also inaccurate for `exp > 6` (even before converting to decimal):

```
exp  Math.Pow(256,exp)        Expected value
---  -----------------------  -----------------------
  5            1099511627776            1099511627776
  6          281474976710656          281474976710656
  7        72057594037927900        72057594037927936
  8     18446744073709600000     18446744073709551616
  9   4722366482869650000000   4722366482869645213696
```

This means I gave up trying to use this method, and just defined:

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, decimal> PowersOf256 = new Dictionary<int, decimal>()
    {
        {0, 1m},
        {1, 256m},
        {2, 65536m},
        {3, 16777216m},
        {4, 4294967296m},
        {5, 1099511627776m},
        {6, 281474976710656m},
        {7, 72057594037927936m}, 
        {8, 18446744073709551616m},
        {9, 4722366482869645213696m},
        {10, 1208925819614629174706176m},
        {11, 309485009821345068724781056m},
        // 256^12 is > decimal.MaxValue
    };
```

and now simply use:

```
    num * PowersOf256[exp]
```

Comment: Maybe not enough precision for double. Try converting every operand to decimal _before_ calculating. I.e. also the parameters to the `Pow` function call, to trigger the decimal overload of the function.

Comment: @UweKeim There is no decimal overload for `Math.Pow()`

Comment: This seems like a classic precision problem to me. What part don't you understand?

Comment: @CodyGray VS debugger shows me the value is a double `1125899906842624`. If I call `((double)1125899906842624).ToString()` I get `1.12589990684262E+15` (which is consistent with getting 1125899906842620m). Why the discrepancy? If it was always `1.12589990684262E+15` I'd totally understand and I wouldn't have asked. The fact that VS debugger was showing me the correct number, but not the actual number that was being added is really what threw me off.

Comment: Hmm, with all those numbers, it's hard to see what's actually going on. I *think* you're saying that the debugger is showing you greater precision than you're actually seeing when you print the value as a string? That would be explained by the fact that `ToString` only uses 15 bits of precision, max, whereas `double` internally supports 17 bits of precision (or is it 18? can't remember).

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah I understand it's hard to see. But yes, the debugger is showing greater precision. [Double supports "15-16 digits"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It looks as if the debugger sees all 16 digits, but the ToString() conversion and cast to decimal only support 15 digits ... but I don't understand why that would be. You can try this yourself: Go put `(double)1125899906842624` and `(decimal)(double)1125899906842624` in the watch window (I'm using VS2015).

Comment: The explicit cast apparently forces it to drop the excess precision that is maintained internally. [The documentation for `Double.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) says: "By default, the return value only contains 15 digits of precision although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally."

Comment: The number is 2^50, which is a power of 2 that can be represented exactly even in a `float`. The decimal representation is limited to a particular number of digits (varying according to internal precision, as you've found). This is usually what you want, because otherwise you'd end up a with a lot of "random" digits in the base 10 representation. Precisely *because* you're dealing with (multiples of) exact powers of 2, though, whatever you're doing with them may have a broader and more efficient implementation than whatever you're doing with `decimal`, depending on how long they stay that way.